# AccessViolationException when we use twain_32.dll for scanning in windows 8.1

Tags: scanning, twain, twaindotnet

I have an application which communicates with scanner and gets the image , it is working fine till windows 7 but it is failing in windows 8.1, we use twain(twain_32.dll) library for scanning purpose, Kindly help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure that the application id and source id which you are passing
>   to twain.dll is not null. From windows 8 and above, the ids can not be
>   null due to security reasons.